# Fix > so that it works for disabled people

Tags: bug, status-norepro

As best I can tell there is an incompatibility with text to speech software for the citation material using ">". Would someone take a look at it?

[How does calling someone an "idiot" make one bound for Gehenna?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/how-does-calling-someone-an-idiot-make-one-subject-for-gehenna?noredirect=1#comment68410_28162)

User Bye can provide more information and correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point in downvoting this: reporting the issue seems to me to be the right thing to do. Having looked at the HTML of the question, I can't see any reason why web-to-speech should have failed to find the link, though.

Comment: The link in that question is actually before the quote block, not inside it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually think the problem is with the blockquote syntax, but rather that the translation was embedded in the URL of the link and not listed in the text of the question.

I would recommend an alternate strategy of including the [translation in the text of the post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/38/914).

Comment: The HTML of the link is constructed entirely normally, though. `<a href="URL">Link text to read out</a>` The structure of the URL shouldn't matter.